# Detect and disassemble binary files using magic number in Vim

Tags: vim

**In vim script, how to detect a file type using magic numbers then transparently assemble/disassemble it?**

Specifically, I would like to detect LLVM Bytecode and disassemble/reassemble it on the fly when I open/write it.

Today I have the assemble/disassemble part as follow:

```
" LLVM-IR to/from LLVM-BC
augroup LLVMBC
    au BufReadPre   *.bc setl binary
    au BufReadPost  *.bc silent %!llvm-dis
    au BufReadPost  *.bc setl filetype=llvm nobinary
    au BufWritePre  *.bc setl binary
    au BufWritePre  *.bc silent %!llvm-as
    au BufWritePost *.bc undo
    au BufWritePost *.bc setl nobinary nomod
augroup END
```

But that only works if the file extension is `.bc`. The magic number for LLVM Bytecode files is `"BC\0xC0\0xDE"` (`BC` in ASCII followed by `0xC0DE` in hexa, 4 bytes in total).

How to:

- match that magic number (without plugin)
- run those Buf{Read,Write}{Pre,Post} command on those filetypes (and not file extension)

I am thinking I should have a stand-alone function that detect the magic number (on any filename) and then add those command on the current buffer (again, on any filename).

Answer (score 0):

I got the detection working (although it reads the "entire first line" which could be long and is rather meaningless for a binary file).

```
function DetectLLVMBC()
    if getline(1) ~= 'BC\%xC0\%xDE'
        setl binary
        silent %!llvm-dis
        setl ft=llvm nobinary
    endif
endfunction
```

Then I add:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * call DetectLLVMBC()
```

To my `augroup LLVMBC`.

But this will **not** re-assemble the file when I save it.

Comment: You will have to write another function for the re-assembling step and call it in a `BufWritePost` autocommand.

Comment: Can I "schedule" that in the DetectLLVMBC? How do I remember it was a .bc file?

Comment: Another function is preferable, I think. You can use buffer-scoped variables to remember things on a specific buffer: `let b:is_LLVMBC = 1`.